# How to interpret predictions from multi labels in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, artificial-intelligence

Say I use a (convolutional) neural network to classify a multi-label problem. For example, the problem is classifying different stages of skin cancer from 0 (healthy) to 4 (severe). The five stages are represented in the following manner.

```
0 => [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
1 => [1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
2 => [1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
3 => [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
4 => [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

In the last layer of my neural network, I have 5 output neurons that use a sigmoid activation function.

After I've trained my neural network, I feed it a test image and it gives me the following prediction.

```
[0.6, 0.2, 0.7, 0.1, 0.1]
```

If any class output greater than 0.5 activates a class, I get the following prediction.

```
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

**My question is, should this correspond to a prediction of 2, 1 or 0?**

Comment: Since you have ordered outcomes, you would benefit immensely from using a model that's appropriate for ordered outcomes. For example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_logit

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140061/how-to-set-up-neural-network-to-output-ordinal-data